# Arraylist not working correctly with cursor query

Tags: java, sqlite, arraylist

I have a cursor which is returning the 5 most recent results from my DB query below.

```
    public Cursor totaldistance(){
    String[] columns = new String[] { DatabaseHelper._ID, DatabaseHelper.DSNM, DatabaseHelper.SDATE };
    Cursor cursor = database.query(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME, columns, null, null, null, null, DatabaseHelper._ID + " DESC limit 5");
    if (cursor != null) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return cursor;
}
```

I then assign the returned cursor values to the arraylist below. It works ok accept the arrayList is missing the latest db record value. For example I can have 4 values in the DB but the 2nd most recent value is being assigned to position 0 in the arraylist. I’m not sure if my cursor query or while statement is the problem. Does anyone know? Thanks!

```
        List<String> distancearray = new ArrayList<String>();
    distancearray.add("0");
    distancearray.add("0");
    distancearray.add("0");
    distancearray.add("0");
    distancearray.add("0");
    int i = 0;

    while(DistanceArray.moveToNext()){
        String uname = DistanceArray.getString(DistanceArray.getColumnIndex("distance"));

        distancearray.set(i, uname);
        i++;
    }
```

Based on the suggestion below I updated my code. It is now retrieving the first result from the database but it is not looping through the next 4. After running the code below my arraylist should read 10,8,6,1,0 but the actual result is 10,10,10,10,0 . It is repeating the first retrieved value.How can I fix the do while operation to write the correct results to the array? Thanks!

```
        List<String> distancearray = new ArrayList<String>();
    distancearray.add(0, "0");
    distancearray.add(1, "0");
    distancearray.add(2, "0");
    distancearray.add(3, "0");
    distancearray.add(4, "0");
    Cursor cursor =  dbManager.totaldistance();
    do{
        String uname = DistanceArray.getString(DistanceArray.getColumnIndex("distance"));
        distancearray.set(i, uname);
        Log.i("Graph", "Value i = " + i);
        Log.i("Graph", "Array value = " + uname);
        i++;
    }while ((cursor.moveToNext()));
```

Comment: What is DistanceArray here ?

Comment: The db records I want store in the Arraylist are user entered distance values. For example my returned query to the distancearray should read 10,8,6,5,0 . But the array when used shows 8,6,5,0,0 .

Comment: Where are you using your cursor in arraylist population code

Comment: Sorry I left that out. Cursor DistanceArray = dbManager.totaldistance();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you are "losing" one row invoking `cursor.moveToFirst();`

```
public Cursor totaldistance(){
    String[] columns = new String[] { DatabaseHelper._ID, DatabaseHelper.DSNM, DatabaseHelper.SDATE };
    Cursor cursor = database.query(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME, columns, null, null, null, null, DatabaseHelper._ID + " DESC limit 5");
    if (cursor != null) {
        // Here you are pointing to the first row of the cursor
        // you need to add this row content into your list  
        cursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return cursor;
}
```

So as you are invoking `moveToFirs()` in the previous method your code to add all rows to the list should looks like

```
List<String> distancearray = new ArrayList<String>();
Cursor cursor =  dbManager.totaldistance();
do{
    distancearray.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("distance")));
}while ((cursor.moveToNext()));

// Be sure here to have at least the 5 desired elements into the list
while(distancearray.size() < 5){
    distancearray.add("0");
}
```

Comment: I see what you mean, while(DistanceArray.moveToNext is skipping the first record. I'm not sure how to apply the fix you suggest to my code however. I tried your suggestion but it didn't work. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the update. I think i'm getting closer but I still have a problem. You can see from my code I am initialising the arraylist with 5 "0" Values. I then want to overwrite these  "0" values with the results of the query. That is why I use i++ . If I don't initialise the arraylist and I have less than 5 values my app crashes as there aren't enough values to plot to a fixed 5 value graph. Do you know how I can implement that in the do while code? Thanks!

Comment: I've updated my question based on your code. It is now retrieving the first value but not looping correctly to update the other array positions. Do you know what is wrong? Thanks!

Comment: in the do/while loop you are never reading the cursor content, you need to call something like `cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("distance"))`

Comment: Thank you, the updated answer code works perfectly and makes way more sense that what I was trying to do! Thanks a million! :-)